# How to find cheap accommodation with prices in random towns in Vietnam?

Tags: online-resources, applications, tips-and-tricks, accommodation, vietnam

I had this problem in Laos too but it seems to be bigger in Vietnam.

Very few accommodations are listed in Booking.com which I mostly use in other countries. I'm sure they do in bigger tourist destinations or at the higher end. But I'm roaming random from the Cau Treo border crossing and there's hardly anything on Booking.com in these places.

I mostly use Google Maps when Booking.com doesn't work, but...

In the areas around here that I've checked almost no accommodations have any prices listed on Google Maps!

Google Maps has two other problems that I should mention: Many cheap places don't show up at all. There's a price filter that cuts off too high at the budget end. If you put it too low, all accommodations disappear from the map, even ones that you know the price of, or it leaves way too many places on the map way above your budget mixed in with the cheap places and you have to go through them manually.

So I'm wondering, is there another site that people in the know use for Vietnam? Maybe a local Vietnamese site? Or a Vietnamese accommodation app? Or some other tricks that people use?

Comment: Have you tried Agoda? I've heard it's better in SE Asia but I'm not confident about that.

Comment: I used to use it just as much as Booking.com but they do some borderline scammy stuff. Like booking via Booking.com so that your reference number doesn't match, or telling you prices lower than are possible to get, etc. But I'll give it a try again...

Comment: Agoda here seems to be the same as Booking.com which isn't a surprise when you know Agoda will even make bookings through Booking.com which can confuse guests and accommodations alike. I'm currently in Tay Son, Ha Tinh, where there are four accommodations in town, and one each a couple of km to the east and west. One is missing from Google Maps and all but one are missing from both Booking.com and Agoda.

Comment: Why don't you ask the landlord while renting whether they are using any web service to advertise their place?

Comment: There are some alternate sites such as mytour.vn (never used them) but I don't see much variation between them and Agoda/Booking.com. Ctrip might be worth a try. Baidu maps seems better in some countries than Google (but not so much .vn). If you find something I hope you'll self-answer this one.